# ASP.NET: GridView's background in an HTML Table also changes color (mouse hover)

Tags: html, asp.net, css, gridview

I have 3 gridviews in a table, 3 < td >. I created a CSS class to change color of Gridview rows upon mouse-hover. But the problem is, the BACKGROUND OF GRIDVIEWS ALSO CHANGE COLOR. So when I hover the cursor, each row changes color but also the background (< td >, the back of the gridview also) changes color. How do I change color of my gridviews' rows only?

Code:

```
<style type="text/css">

        .CSSTable
        {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 60%; /*Fits the <div>*/
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
    .CSSTable table
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        width: 100%; /*sets table all aligned*/
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .CSSTable tr:last-child td:last-child
    {
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    }
    .CSSTable table tr:first-child td:first-child
    {
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    }
    .CSSTable table tr:first-child td:last-child
    {
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    }
    .CSSTable tr:last-child td:first-child
    {
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    }
    .CSSTable tr:hover td
    {
    }
    .CSSTable tr:nth-child(odd)
    {
        background-color: #e5e5e5;
    }
    .CSSTable tr:nth-child(even)
    {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .CSSTable td
    {
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 7px;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #000000;
    }
    .CSSTable tr:last-child td
    {
        border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    }
    .CSSTable tr td:last-child
    {
        border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    }
    .CSSTable tr:last-child td:last-child
    {
        border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    .CSSTable tr:first-child td
    {
        background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #4c4c4c 5%, #000000 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #4c4c4c), color-stop(1, #000000) );
        background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #4c4c4c 5%, #000000 100% );
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#4c4c4c", endColorstr="#000000");
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#4c4c4c,000000);
        background-color: #4c4c4c;
        border: 0px solid #000000;
        text-align: center;
        border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .CSSTable tr:first-child:hover td
    {
        background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #4c4c4c 5%, #000000 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #4c4c4c), color-stop(1, #000000) );
        background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #4c4c4c 5%, #000000 100% );
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#4c4c4c", endColorstr="#000000");
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#4c4c4c,000000);
        background-color: #4c4c4c;
    }
    .CSSTable tr:first-child td:first-child
    {
        border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    }
    .CSSTable tr:first-child td:last-child
    {
        border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    }
    .CSSTable tr:hover
    {
        background-color:Gray;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you haven't posted the pertinent html markup related to the this question I'm going to guess you have added the `CSSTable` class to your wrapper table? For example, if you have this html hierarchy...

```
<table class="CSSTable">
    <tr>
        <td><asp:GridView>...</asp:GridView></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:GridView>...</asp:GridView></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:GridView>...</asp:GridView></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

you should change it to...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:GridView CssClass="CSSTable">...</asp:GridView></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:GridView CssClass="CSSTable">...</asp:GridView></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:GridView CssClass="CSSTable">...</asp:GridView></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or if you are only targeting the row hover just create a css class to handle the hover event and then set the `CssClass` property of the `RowStyle` element...

```
<asp:GridView>
     <RowStyle CssClass="" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You have just expanded my knowledge on more possible techniques in formatting css tables. Thanks!